# How to change the login hyper link to logout when successfully logged in

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have created a login page but when the user logs in I want to change the log in button to logout .I have created the log in  buttons in my Site.Master . Can someone tell me how to do that....

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header_in">


    <div id="menu">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.aspx">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="ourwork.aspx">Our Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.aspx">Login / Register</a></li>

     </ul>
```

this following code is for the login

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM WhatTypes where UserName = '" + txtUN.Text + "' AND Password ='" + txtP.Text + "'", con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        //ID = dr["ID"].ToString(); 
        Session["user"] = dr["UserLevel"];
       // Session["FirstName"] = dr["First Name"];
        if (Session["user"].ToString() == "A")
        {
            Response.Redirect("AdminPanel.aspx");

        }
        else if (Session["user"].ToString() == "M")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Activity.aspx");

        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblinvalidlogin.Visible = true;
        lblinvalidlogin.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
    }

}
```

Comment: You need client side JavaScript - to change the link pointing to logout

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee: The webserver that is serving up the html should determine that beforehand and send the html correctly. It should not be determined client side unless you are using ajax or something, and even then the information is still being sent from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add c# code inside aspx page like this -

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.aspx">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="ourwork.aspx">Our Works</a></li>
    <% if (Session["user"] == null) { %>
        <li><a href="login.aspx">Login / Register</a></li>
    <% } else { %>
        <li><a href="logout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
    <%} %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have a boolean property in the code behind say Logged

you can make the Logged property static and do the following

```
<% if(! MasterPageCodeBehindClass.Logged))
      {
      /// your logout link
      }
    else
      {
    ///render your login link
      }
    %>
```

Comment: He is not asking for login vs logout pages. He wants to change the "login" hyperlink on ALL of his pages to "logout" after the user is logged in.

Comment: yeah...that is just comment...he can add this code on the master page and done